# Is a thread the right choice to test continuously Internet connection?

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, qthread, ui-thread

I'm building a Python 3 and PyQt application that connects to a Web service to download some data based on a user action. So I need to know whether a Internet connection is available or not. I currently have wrapped all methods that need a connection to work in a similar way as follows

```
def method():
    if is_online():
        #do stuff
    else:
        #throw error
```

Where `is_online` is simply a function that tries to connect to Google via an HTTP request.

Now the question: what if I used a thread with a `while` loop to check for Internet connection and warn the user right after he loses connection so I can avoid wrapping methods? It seems not Pythonic. Is this too resource consuming? Is there a third better way to do it?

**Edit 1:** I clarified what the `is_online` function does.

Comment: You can write a decorator to wrap the methods, which means you only have to write the code once and then annotate all methods that require an internet connection. There are tons of examples on google to get you started. Also, "Where is_online is simply a function which pings Google." - "pings" as in sending a ping (ICMP), or sending an HTTP request and seeing if you get an answer? ICMP is often blocked by firewalls and is thus not very reliable, you should use HTTP here.

Comment: @l4mpi yeah, I really wanted to say "HTTP request", not a "real" ping, sorry for confusion (I'll edit the question). I'll have a look at decorators, thanks for the hint.

Comment: Why don't you just try to contact the real web service and handle timeouts etc. if they happen? Just because Google is answering you doesn't mean that the target web service is also reachable.

Comment: @Jasper because if the service does not respond, whose fault is it? Missing internet connection or the web service? I need to narrow down the problem and present it to the user so I can say that there's no connection (so stop trying) or try again later because the service isn't responding. Is there a way to know whose fault is it by checking the web service?

Comment: Does it matter (for the user) what the "real" problem is? Why would you "stop trying" if there's no connection, it might come back? As an answer to your question, decorators or a dedicated thread both seem OK to me.

Comment: I think it is reasonable to do the online check in another QThread instead of in the main, as this check may last more than 1 second, this may leads to your UI freezing, so, the correct way is to move this kind of time-consuming work into back-end thread. If you are worrying that this kind of detecting is not so "pythonic", you could add this detect function to an existing back-end thread (possibly using the QTimer to schedule a regular check at interals)